# Grammar parse tree

Tags: parse-tree

We're given the following Grammar

R → XRX|S

S → aT b|bT a

T → XT X|X|

X → a|b

And asked to give the derivation and parse tree for the string 'abab'

I'm not fully sure how this works, I've tried R → S → aTb → abTab → abab for the derivation and I know how to get the parse tree once the derivation is right, but I'm just wondering if I'm going the write direction in writing the derivation for said Grammar

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have skipped a couple steps in your derivation. Here's a complete one, with the left-hand side of each step highlighted with **boldface**:

- **R** [R → S]
- **S** [S → T]
- a**T**b [T → XTX]
- a**X**TXb [X → b]
- abT**X**b [X → a]
- ab**T**ab [T → ε]
- abab